# How to not mix up class variables using multiple inheritance?

Tags: python, multiple-inheritance

I need to create a 'Balance' class which will be a son of two parent classes 'Income' and 'Expenses'. 'Income' and 'Expenses' should be conteiners where I will put some numbers and find the difference between sum of 'Income' and sum of 'Expenses' later on.

```
from dataclasses import dataclass


@dataclass
class Income:

    first_Income: int = 0
    second_Income: int = 0
    third_Income: int = 0

    def all_vars_Income(self):
        return [attr for attr in dir(self) if not callable(getattr(self, attr)) and not attr.startswith('__')]

    def sum_Income(self):
        return sum([getattr(self, var) for var in self.all_vars_Income()])


@dataclass
class Expenses:

    first_Expenses: int = 0
    second_Expenses: int = 0
    third_Expenses: int = 0

    def all_vars_Expenses(self):
        return [attr for attr in dir(self) if not callable(getattr(self, attr)) and not attr.startswith('__')]

    def sum_Expenses(self):
        return sum([getattr(self, var) for var in self.all_vars_Expenses()])


class Balance(Income, Expenses):
    def sum_Balance(self):
        return Income.sum_Income(self) - Expenses.sum_Expenses(self)


user = Balance()
print(Balance.all_vars_Income(user))
# ['first_Expenses', 'first_Income', 'second_Expenses', 'second_Income', 'third_Expenses', 'third_Income']
print(Income.all_vars_Income(user))
# ['first_Expenses', 'first_Income', 'second_Expenses', 'second_Income', 'third_Expenses', 'third_Income']
print(Income.all_vars_Income(Income))
# ['first_Income', 'second_Income', 'third_Income']
user.__setattr__('first_Income', 50)
user.__setattr__('second_Expenses', 100)
print(Income.sum_Income(user))
# 150
print(user.sum_Balance())
# 0
```

So, the problem is, as you can see, that variables of the first class and the variables of the second class are kinda mixed up. I want to keep variables within approriate classes and use only sum of those variables to be able to count the difference.
When I this line `"user.__setattr__('first_Income', 50)"`, I want to change the value of the Income class only, so that I could keep the sum of all variables of the Expenses class equals to 0.
Probably, it was chaotic but I hope you get the point.

Comment: Why not make your expenses a simple list of 3 values, rather than this complicated and not flexible structure that forces you to things like `[attr for attr in dir(self) if not callable(getattr(self, attr)) and not attr.startswith('__')]`?

Comment: I can have not 3 values here, but much more. So, if there will be many values, I think it's more efficient way to do that. Actually, I'm new to python, so I might be mistaken. If so, I'm good to be corrected

Comment: Yeah well... That's what happens if you inherit from two classes with different attributes, your subclass will have the attributes of both classes. I agree with what @ThierryLathuille said, your way to structure the classes looks very complicated and lists would definitely make your life way easier.

Comment: @Jeffery-the-newbie If you can have more or some undefined number of values, just use a list. Really.

Comment: Ok, thank you for your feedback. I will change that. But I can't believe that there is no way to do want I to do. Should I just stop playing around with the multiple inheritance and do my things without it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I propose this way to build your code, which not only solves your main problems but also complies with python's style guide and makes better use of classes' capabilities and functionalities (although for simplicity I've omitted handling of exceptions):

```py
from dataclasses import dataclass, field


@dataclass
class Income:
    incomes: list[int] = field(default_factory=list)

    def sum_incomes(self):
        return sum(self.incomes)

    def add_income(self, income):
        self.incomes.append(income)

    def modify_income(self, number, income):
        self.incomes[number] = income


@dataclass
class Expenses:
    expenses: list[int] = field(default_factory=list)

    def sum_expenses(self):
        return sum(self.expenses)

    def add_expense(self, expense):
        self.expenses.append(expense)

    def modify_expense(self, number, expense):
        self.expenses[number] = expense


@dataclass
class Balance(Income, Expenses):
    def sum_balance(self):
        return self.sum_incomes() - self.sum_expenses()


user = Balance()
user.add_income(50)
user.add_expense(100)
print(user.sum_incomes())
# 50
print(user.sum_balance())
# -50
user.modify_income(0, 200)
print(user.sum_balance())
# 100
```

Comment: Wow, thank you. I'm really impressed how much simplier and more readable the code became. I wish this community would have more people like you. Sadly, I cannot even upvote your answer yet (due to 0 reputation) but I am so thankful for your response.

Comment: You're welcome. The problem is probably that you're just not familiar enough with OOP and python yet, and tried to use classes and magic methods (the ones that start by `__`) in a rather complicated way. Practice makes perfect. And there are lots of people eager to help in here, sooner or later somebody else would have probably answered something very similar to this, or some variation, possibly better.

Comment: Yeah, I'm very new to OOP and programming in general. I found out about magic methods a couple of days ago, so I just wanted to use this fancy thing :). But seriously, I have no experience with that and this is my first project with classes (I am making a budget app). There are many things are yet to be known, so I am glad someone helps me. Thanks again and don't stop making people like me happy :)

Comment: You usually don't want to use magic methods, there's almost always a better way to do what you want, and you can leave the usage of magic methods to the internals of python itself. For example, to add 1 + 2, you could do `int.__add__(1, 2)`, but that's actually what `1 + 2` does. In your case, you could have done `setattr(user, 'first_Income', 50)`, avoiding the usage of the `__setattr__` magic method but, in your code, that's actually the same as `user.first_Income = 50`. They're very interesting and you can make your code really powerful when you override them in your classes.

Comment: Oh, actually, I found out about this thing `__setattr__` and `__getattr__` only yesterday. I needed to add value to a given variable. Something like that `user.add_income('salary', 50)` And I didn't find a better way to use setattr and getattr. Yes, it's very strange. And my code was way more complicated even then the version of it in the very start of this question. Now, thanks to you, I know a little bit more about magic methods.

Comment: Cool! Keep it up and learn even more about this so loved language.